# Shortest Path - INOI 2014

Tags: c++

After googling for about an hour, I still haven't found a satisfactory, complete, explanation for the "Shortest Path" problem (attached herewith). I know that there are various methods to do this, such as Dijkstra / Bellman-Ford / Floyd-Warshall etc. but I just cant understand the code. I get the logic alright, its just that there's no one out there who also gives a step by step explanation for the code too.
I'm sure this explanation would not just help me, but many others out there too!

Its problem number 2 "Free Ticket" : [INOI 2014 Paper](http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/2014/inoi2014/inoi2014-qpaper.pdf)

P.S. I got problem 1 on my own (Yay :D) , the one for which I asked a doubt on in my last question and I got a -1  :-(

P.P.S. I hope the question was well written.... if not, please do notify cause stack overflow says I'm about to get banned :-/

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is. Are you asking us to write this code for you? Are you asking us to go Google solutions for you? Both of those requests are off-topic for Stack Overflow. This site is for small specific questions, such as if you try to implement this code yourself and get stuck, you can ask about your implementation.

Comment: lol... no one has a satisfactory complete explanation for any of those algorithms? That was a good one.

Comment: Um sir, I was wondering if you could explain the logic to me in an easy to understand manner, that's it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method: Apply **Dijkstra** on every vertex of the graph and find out the global maximum of the cost between any two nodes on the graph.

Explanation: As you can see through the method, this is a naive method to calculate the maximum cost between any two routes, because we have to consider **all** the nodes as the **source node** and get the shortest paths from the source node to **every other node on the graph** (This condition is specified in the problem), and then **maximize** the cost of travelling i.e. maximizing the weight of the shortest path between any two nodes. (This condition is also mentioned in the problem). As Dijkstra is quite efficient with a **minimum heap** (Time complexity : `O( (V+E)lgV )`), this solution runs perfectly in the time limit alloted by the INOI server.

For reference, you can see my code : [FreeTicket Solution](http://pastebin.com/WEMfKbbd)

Hope that helped. If not, please comment.

Comment: It was really good, but I was wondering if there would be any other way to do it, as these "heap" functions are a bit new to me.... It would be nice if you could come up with another solution involving other methods,or even better, write the dijankstra's in an easier way such that a 10th grader can understand it :P or even better, check out the code I've written, using Floyed-Warshall and explain to me why it doesn't work.....

Comment: You could use Dijkstra's with a **priority queue** too, but I can't guarantee that it wouldn't cause a TLE. And I'm sorry, I'm yet to study Floyd-Warshall, so I could tell your implementation after studying up. :) And yeah, start studying up, INOI is just 3 days away.

Comment: If it helped, please press that gray tick to make that green! :)

Comment: It helped alright, but I'm sorry, I don't have enough reputation (1)  :-( but :  [Here's a gift for you](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/48877/data-structures-and-algorithms)  and best of luck for INOI 2015!

Comment: Hey, you just have to click the gray tick below my answer. No reputation needed to accept any answer! And yeah! I have that link, but thanks for that, too. Best of luck to you, too! :)